# How to make ProgressBar progress in alertDialog?(Xamarin.Android)

Tags: xamarin.android, progress-bar

I have the following code in `alertDialog.SetPositiveButton`

```
alertConfirmTransfer.SetPositiveButton("ДА", delegate
{
    ProgressBar progressBar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar);
    alertConfirmTransfer.Cancel();
    MobileSellReference.Service1 service = new 
    MobileSellReference.Service1();
    progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(10);
    service.Url = settings.Synchronization.Msellurl;
    progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(10);
    byte[][] resultFromService = service.ToPPC(basedataZipName, objectId);
    progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(10);
    byte[] basedataZipFile = resultFromService[0];
    byte[] dutybasedataZipFile = resultFromService[3];
    byte[] tranbasedataZipFile = resultFromService[2];
    byte[] vendbasedataZipFile = resultFromService[1];
    progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(10);

    string basedataZipFullPath = GlobalVariables.fromserverFolderPath + "/" + basedataZipName;
    string dutybasedataZipFullPath = GlobalVariables.fromserverFolderPath + "/" + dutybasedataZipName;
    string tranbasedataZipFullPath = GlobalVariables.fromserverFolderPath + "/" + tranbasedataZipName;
    string vendbasedataZipFullPath = GlobalVariables.fromserverFolderPath + "/" + vendbasedataZipName;

    Helper.DeleteAllFromFolders(GlobalVariables.fromserverFolderPath, GlobalVariables.vendingFolderPath, GlobalVariables.tranFolderPath, GlobalVariables.debtFolderPath);
    progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(10);
    Helper.EmptyMobileSellDB();
    progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(10);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(basedataZipFullPath, basedataZipFile);
    progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(10);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(dutybasedataZipFullPath, dutybasedataZipFile);
    progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(10);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tranbasedataZipFullPath, tranbasedataZipFile);
    progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(10);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(vendbasedataZipFullPath, vendbasedataZipFile);
    progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(10);
}
```

I want the progress bar to increment in the places I specified . But when I run the app I have only progress bar circulating infinetly. I want to increase by and by. And After reaching 100 to dissapear. I've found too little information how to do that in Xamarin.Android and none of it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

After the line where you findviewbyreference :

```
ProgressBar progressBar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar);
```

Set the max progress to 100 and then set the current progress to 0.

```
progressBar.Max = 100;
progressBar.Progress = 0;
```

Then incrementing the progress should work.

```
progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(10);
```

// Try adding delay after/before you set the progress.
// You can put the below code in a method and call that method after updating the progress bar.

```
              try
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Android.Util.Log.Error("Error",exception.Message);
                }
```

Comment: progress increases at once not little by little

Comment: Probably the task is getting executed very quick that you are unable to see the progress getting updated step by step. Try adding a delay, check my edited answer.

Comment: I've put `Thread.Sleep(2000)` after or before every `IncrementProgressBy` call but it still does the same increase the progress at once.

Comment: Can you please post your xaml and *.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

cs file

```
MobileSellReference.Service1 service = new MobileSellReference.Service1();
service.Url = settings.Synchronization.Msellurl;
progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(10);
Thread.Sleep(2000);

byte[][] resultFromService = service.ToPPC(basedataZipName, objectId);
progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(50);
Thread.Sleep(2000);

byte[] basedataZipFile = resultFromService[0];
byte[] dutybasedataZipFile = resultFromService[3];
byte[] tranbasedataZipFile = resultFromService[2];
byte[] vendbasedataZipFile = resultFromService[1];

string basedataZipFullPath = GlobalVariables.fromserverFolderPath + "/" + basedataZipName;
string dutybasedataZipFullPath = GlobalVariables.fromserverFolderPath + "/" + dutybasedataZipName;
string tranbasedataZipFullPath = GlobalVariables.fromserverFolderPath + "/" + tranbasedataZipName;
string vendbasedataZipFullPath = GlobalVariables.fromserverFolderPath + "/" + vendbasedataZipName;

Helper.DeleteAllFromFolders(GlobalVariables.fromserverFolderPath,         GlobalVariables.vendingFolderPath, GlobalVariables.tranFolderPath,     GlobalVariables.debtFolderPath);
progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(5);
Thread.Sleep(2000);
Helper.EmptyMobileSellDB();
progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(5);
Thread.Sleep(2000);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(basedataZipFullPath, basedataZipFile);
progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(10);
Thread.Sleep(2000);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(dutybasedataZipFullPath, dutybasedataZipFile);
progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(10);
Thread.Sleep(2000);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tranbasedataZipFullPath, tranbasedataZipFile);
progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(10);
Thread.Sleep(2000);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(vendbasedataZipFullPath, vendbasedataZipFile);
```

The code above is in `alert.SetPositiveButton("Yes" ....)` method

the axml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar" />
    <Button
        android:text="Взема данни"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnGetData" />
    <Button
        android:text="Предава данни"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnTransferData" />
    <Button
        android:text="Пълна синхронизация"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnFullSynchronization" />
</LinearLayout>
```